# A Question Of Percentages

Tags: probability, percentages

If I have 4 chances and each chance has a 10% success rate, what is the overall percent chance that 1 chance will succeed?  For example:  A guy plays a roleplaying game.  He has 4 peices of equipment where each peice has a 10% chance rocks will fall from the sky.  The percentages don't stack.  Meaning they don't add up to give a 40% chance.  Each one is worked out independantley.  So what would be the percent chance 1 will succeed out of all the 4?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: Are the chances independent?

Comment: Maybe you should look at the chance of complete failure?

Comment: Some advice on [asking good questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959)...

Comment: What does "overall chance that I succeed" mean to you:  succeed in all attempts, or in at least one attempt?

Comment: at least in 1 attempt

Comment: If it's "at least one success", then first find the probability of all failing, and subtract that from one (or 100%).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** IF the chances are indepndent, than you should think of the binomial distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the chances of success on each attempt are mutually independent (and equal), then the number of successes in the trial has a binomial distribution.  $N\sim\mathcal{Bin}(4, 0.10)$

So the chance that **exactly** $n$ attempts succeed is determined by:

$$\Pr(N = n)={4\choose n}0.10^n0.90^{4-n}$$

However, you want the chance that **at least one** attempt succeeds, which can be more easily found by examining converse: the chance that no attempt succeeds

$$\Pr(N \geq 1)=1-\Pr(N = 0)$$